# vifm: how to paste from clipboard to command line

Tags: paste, vifm

I use vifm on windows. I have a problem: I can't understand how to insert text from a clipboard into a command line.

I have read the manual of vifm and tried looking in the documentation (https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-command-line), but didn't find anything about this

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in facilities for interacting with system's clipboard as of Vifm v0.13.  However, since Vifm runs in a terminal, you can insert into a terminal instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Normal mode, you can use `q:` to open command line history in Vim (if you are in command line mode, you can do the same thing with `Ctrl+G`). The topmost line will be your current command. Then you can paste whatever you need from system clipboard using Vim's registers (`+` or `*`, so command will be `"+p` or `"*p` in Normal mode). Then save and close the file using `:wq`, and Vifm will execute command in the topmost line immediately.